# Allow null in foreign key to user. Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this model

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

When in admin i try to creat a vacancy without a user. And it throws an error " club_vacancy.user_id may not be NULL".
Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> `club_vacancy.user_id may not be NULL`

Looks very much like an error from your database, rather than from Django.

It seems most likely that you added `null=True` after running `manage.py syncdb`. You'll need to modify your database schema to allow null values in that column.

Comment: well i ran syncdb before and after i added null=true. How should i modify my db?

Comment: syncdb does not modify tables which already exist. Drop the table and run syncdb again, or modify your database manually, or use a migrations app.

Comment: migrations app like 'south'

Comment: i didn't know how to drop a table so i deleted the db and creted it again. It works now.

Comment: Newer Django versions have migrations built in.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from South, another option is to use django evolution for schema changes.

http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/

Install it before making db changes. Then run

```
python manage.py evolve --hint --execute
```

Make sure that if you add a new field, you allow nulls (`null=True`) or else evolve will give you an error message.

Comment: what if i don't want to allow the new field to be null? What do i do?

Comment: Newer Django versions have migrations built in.

Answer (score -5):

you need to reset you database table (since just syncdb does not update fields that are alredy created with null=False)

./manage.py reset your_app

OR if there is some data that you do not want to loose use SQL commands to remove NOT NULL flag