# 'NOT NULL constraint failed' even with 'null=True'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I see this error when I run my code:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.category_id
```

Here is the code:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Запись'
        verbose_name_plural='Записи'

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Theme', default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Заголовок')
    text = RichTextField(verbose_name='Текст')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Время создания',default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Время публикации',blank=True, null=True)


    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
    def approved_commentimages(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Theme(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Категория'
        verbose_name_plural='Категории'

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=40)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Транслит', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

What am I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow null in foreign key to user. Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812806/allow-null-in-foreign-key-to-user-django)

Comment: And to expand on that - have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` for the app after you made that change?

Comment: yes, i am use migrations after changes. that's error happened just where i try do it.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if you delete or modify migration files, your actual database can get out of sync with your model files and when you run `makemigrations` it might say no changes detected, even though the file is different from the actual database.

You can verify this by logging into your MySQL database and check the actual null constraints. You will see that it probably says that it can't be null even though your file say it can.

The easiest solution to this is to just create a new database and run `migrate`. However if you already have a lot of data in your database and want to avoid making a new one and migrating your data, you can try to sync the database with your model again manually.

Comment: Did this help you?